# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/app/staticfiles/admin/css/widgets.css'

Tags: django, docker

Someone can help me?
I didnt know why this error happends i give permission to django file app
in chown -R appuser /app

More detail:
i use docker-compose build
and docker-compose up
my project tree:
[https://i.ibb.co/WKwWFgw/aaa.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Ecp.png)
my files:

Dockerfile:

```
    # For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13


EXPOSE 8000

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"
# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && pip install Pillow && apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo
# more pip
RUN pip install psycopg2
#end more pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

COPY /app /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
# File wsgi.py was not found in subfolder: 'default_docker_project'. Please enter the Python path to wsgi file.
ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

```
python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level=DEBUG app.wsgi
```

requirements.txt

```
django==3.1.1,<4.0.0
gunicorn==20.0.4,<29.0.0
whitenoise>=5.0.1,<5.1
django-db-prefix==1.0.5,<1.2.0
django-taggit>=1.4.0,<1.9.9
django-crispy-forms>=1.11.2,<1.99.9
Markdown==3.3.4
social-auth-app-django==4.0.0
```

in app app
urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for app project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')), 'changeme')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', default=True)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
if ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV.split(','))


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # user APPS
    "blog.apps.BlogConfig",
    "taggit",
    # "django.contrib.sites",
    # "django.contrib.sitemaps",
    "account.apps.AccountConfig",
    # "social_django",
    # "django_extensions",
    "images.apps.ImagesConfig",
    "crispy_forms",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = ['django_db_prefix', ] + INSTALLED_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DB_PREFIX = "db_krzyzak21_space_"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('PORT'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Default logging

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[DJANGO] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
            '%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logs/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}

# More

LOGIN_URL = "login"
LOGOUT_URL = "logout"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "profile"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "base"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "account.authentication.EmailAuthBackend",
    "social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2",
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

# EMAILS
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER'),
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'),
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# SOCIAL
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY'),
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = os.getenv('SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
```

my error:
its happening with all files admin

```
krzyzak21@DESKTOP-PBESVTN:/mnt/m/WorkspaceDjango/krzyzak21space_docker$ docker-compose up                                                                                                                                                      
Starting krzyzak21space_docker_app ... done
Attaching to krzyzak21space_docker_app     
app_1  | Operations to perform:
app_1  |   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions, taggit
app_1  | Running migrations:
app_1  |   No migrations to apply.
app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
app_1  |     main()
app_1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
app_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
app_1  |     utility.execute()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
app_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
app_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
app_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle
app_1  |     collected = self.collect()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 118, in collect
app_1  |     handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 355, in copy_file
app_1  |     self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 52, in save
app_1  |     return self._save(name, content)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 291, in _save
app_1  |     os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)
app_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/app/staticfiles/admin/js/actions.js'
krzyzak21space_docker_app exited with code 1
```

Comment: You're showing a lot of information, but the most critical is pretty unclear: what exactly is the error at what point when you do what?

Comment: ok, now i edit my bug in terminal ;)

Comment: Is the `app/staticfiles` directory empty?

Comment: in start yes. collectstatic add there files with use ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]